# Images in between div are not showing

Tags: html, css

So I'm still kind of new around web designing and I'm trying to figure out the solution for this issue. Here's the CSS and HTML code. The images work when it's not sandwiched by div, I've also try changing the image's directory back and forth...

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  color: #020F20;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #020F20;
  font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover {
  color: #F5F49E;
  background-color: #020F20;
}

a:visited {}

#container {
  width: 960px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#header {
  background-image: url('header.jpg');
  height: 150px;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  padding-right: 90px;
  padding-left: 72px;
}

.nav {
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 50px;
  border-top-color: #000000;
  border-bottom-color: #000000;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #F5F49E;
}

.nav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.nav a:active {
  background-color: #F5F49E;
  color: white;
}

#content-area {
  padding: 24px;
}

#page-title {
  font-size: 28px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#page {
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: justify;
}

#footer {
  background-image: url('footer.jpg');
  height: 40px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* This Is For Slide Show Container*/

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* This Is For The Next & Previous Buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* This Is To Position The Next Button To The Right & Vice Versa */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev {
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* This Is For The On Hover, We Are Going To Add Background Color As Black */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
}


/* This Is For The Caption Text Under The Image Display */

.text {
  color: gold;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* This Is For The Number Of The Picture In The Slideshow */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2fF2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: :absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* This Is For The Dots/Bullets/Indicators When The Images Moved To Next Images */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 1 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading Animation where webkit is being used for frames animation. Webkit is a rendering engine for browsers like chrome/safari. Other browsers use different
rendering engine, if the browser won't run your rendering engine, it will just ignore it */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keygframes-fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keygframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* When on smaller screens, decrease the size */

@media only screen and (max-width:300px) {
  .prev,
  .next,
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhmtl1-transiotional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <title>Layout</title>
  <link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header"><br/>Extreme Sports</div>

    <div class="nav">
      <a class="active" href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About Us</a>
      <a href="#">Activities</a>
      <a href="#">Event</a>
      <a href="#">Photos</a>
      <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </div>

    <div id="content-area">
      <div id="page-title">Page Title</div><br/><br/>

      <div id="page-content">

        <div style="margin:8px;" class="slideshow-container">

          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">1/3</div>
            <img alt="" height="350" src="Images/img_snow_wide.jpg" width="100%" />
            <div class="text">My Fruits</div>
          </div>


          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">2/3</div>
            <img alt="nature wide" height="350" src="Images/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" />
            <div class="text">My Wallpaper</div>
          </div>

          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">3/3</div>
            <img alt="" height="350" src="Images/img_nature_wide.jpg" width="100%" />
            <div class="text">My Nature</div>
          </div>


          <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
          <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10094;</a>
        </div>
        <br/><br/><br/>

        <div style="text-align:center">
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          var slideIndex = 1;
          showSlides(slideIndex);

          function currentSlide(n) {
            showSlides(slideIndex += n);
          }

          function currentSlide(n) {
            showSlides(slideIndex = n);
          }

          function showSlides(n) {
            var i;
            var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
            var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
            if (n > slides.length) {
              slideIndex = 1
            }
            if (n < 1) {
              slideIndex = slides.length
            }
            for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
              slides[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
              dots[i].classname = dots[i].className.replace("active", "");
            }
            slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
            dots[slideIndex - 1].className += "active";
          }
        </script>
        <br/><br/>

        <div id="page-article">

          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed id maximus enim. Ut tincidunt velit eu euismod fermentum. Sed lorem lorem, euismod ac venenatis quis, sollicitudin at nulla. Aenean eleifend ullamcorper orci. Sed at sagittis est. Aenean sollicitudin
          arcu id mauris dapibus lacinia. Praesent sed erat vitae arcu suscipit tempus eu ac lacus. In rhoncus est felis, ornare sagittis turpis egestas sollicitudin. In non sapien pellentesque lectus pretium faucibus. Integer eget sollicitudin velit.
          Curabitur eget nunc blandit, maximus lacus quis, congue ipsum. Nam varius hendrerit venenatis.<br/><br/> Morbi hendrerit velit mollis, efficitur nisi imperdiet, vehicula sapien. Aliquam diam orci, ornare ut luctus vitae, faucibus vel
          purus. Mauris auctor pellentesque lacus. Maecenas porttitor felis nec nulla vulputate, ut commodo nunc scelerisque. Sed luctus vitae elit tempor porttitor. Morbi consectetur ante iaculis erat bibendum, eget viverra nunc rutrum. Phasellus placerat,
          lorem consequat ultrices auctor, dui nunc imperdiet justo, a facilisis elit lacus nec mi. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.<br/><br/> Pellentesque aliquam, diam quis pulvinar mattis, sem neque tristique erat, a tincidunt
          elit nisi et est. Duis lorem ipsum, pulvinar eu eros eu, feugiat luctus diam. Cras eget molestie massa. Quisque quis mi quis urna interdum bibendum. Pellentesque at leo varius, placerat ipsum sed, convallis tortor. Integer ut volutpat lorem,
          in efficitur nisl. Sed augue est, vulputate vitae tortor sit amet, molestie ultrices diam. In eget elit urna. Aliquam tincidunt tempor sollicitudin. Phasellus ac elit a risus mattis iaculis id id erat. Sed a mauris in tellus porttitor ornare.
          Pellentesque eget porttitor dui. Duis posuere, dui eu mollis varius, quam diam elementum velit, nec dignissim magna justo ut tellus.<br/><br/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">Created By Alex, 2020<br/>Last Updated 01012020</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Kindly ignore the descriptions, those are just notes for myself.

Comment: Do you really need XHTML? [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML) (HTML5) is a little bit easier to write – it has shorter doctype (just `<!doctyle html>`), there is no need for `/` in self-closing tags, etc.

Comment: my lecturer asks us to use html 1, im not sure why, maybe it's because some of the things that she teaches only works in xhtml 1..

Comment: HTML has less limitations than XHTML. XHTML must be valid XML.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have typos in your code. I modified functions marked `// HERE`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  color: #020F20;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #020F20;
  font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover {
  color: #F5F49E;
  background-color: #020F20;
}

a:visited {}

#container {
  width: 960px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#header {
  background-image: url('header.jpg');
  height: 150px;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  padding-right: 90px;
  padding-left: 72px;
}

.nav {
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 50px;
  border-top-color: #000000;
  border-bottom-color: #000000;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #F5F49E;
}

.nav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.nav a:active {
  background-color: #F5F49E;
  color: white;
}

#content-area {
  padding: 24px;
}

#page-title {
  font-size: 28px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#page {
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: justify;
}

#footer {
  background-image: url('footer.jpg');
  height: 40px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* This Is For Slide Show Container*/

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* This Is For The Next & Previous Buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* This Is To Position The Next Button To The Right & Vice Versa */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev {
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* This Is For The On Hover, We Are Going To Add Background Color As Black */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
}


/* This Is For The Caption Text Under The Image Display */

.text {
  color: gold;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* This Is For The Number Of The Picture In The Slideshow */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2fF2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: :absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* This Is For The Dots/Bullets/Indicators When The Images Moved To Next Images */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 1 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading Animation where webkit is being used for frames animation. Webkit is a rendering engine for browsers like chrome/safari. Other browsers use different
rendering engine, if the browser won't run your rendering engine, it will just ignore it */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keygframes-fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keygframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* When on smaller screens, decrease the size */

@media only screen and (max-width:300px) {
  .prev,
  .next,
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhmtl1-transiotional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <title>Layout</title>
  <link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header"><br/>Extreme Sports</div>

    <div class="nav">
      <a class="active" href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About Us</a>
      <a href="#">Activities</a>
      <a href="#">Event</a>
      <a href="#">Photos</a>
      <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </div>

    <div id="content-area">
      <div id="page-title">Page Title</div><br/><br/>

      <div id="page-content">

        <div style="margin:8px;" class="slideshow-container">

          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">1/3</div>
            <img alt="" height="350" src="Images/img_snow_wide.jpg" width="100%" />
            <div class="text">My Fruits</div>
          </div>


          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">2/3</div>
            <img alt="nature wide" height="350" src="Images/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" />
            <div class="text">My Wallpaper</div>
          </div>

          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">3/3</div>
            <img alt="" height="350" src="Images/img_nature_wide.jpg" width="100%" />
            <div class="text">My Nature</div>
          </div>


          <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
          <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10094;</a>
        </div>
        <br/><br/><br/>

        <div style="text-align:center">
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
          <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          var slideIndex = 1;
          showSlides(slideIndex);

          function plusSlides(n) { // HERE
            showSlides(slideIndex += n);
          }

          function currentSlide(n) {
            showSlides(slideIndex = n);
          }

          function showSlides(n) { // HERE
            var i;
            var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
            var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
            if (n > slides.length) {
              slideIndex = 1
            }
            if (n < 1) {
              slideIndex = slides.length
            }
            for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
              slides[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
              dots[i].classname = dots[i].className.replace("active", "");
            }
            slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
            dots[slideIndex - 1].className += "active";
          }
        </script>
        <br/><br/>

        <div id="page-article">

          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed id maximus enim. Ut tincidunt velit eu euismod fermentum. Sed lorem lorem, euismod ac venenatis quis, sollicitudin at nulla. Aenean eleifend ullamcorper orci. Sed at sagittis est. Aenean sollicitudin
          arcu id mauris dapibus lacinia. Praesent sed erat vitae arcu suscipit tempus eu ac lacus. In rhoncus est felis, ornare sagittis turpis egestas sollicitudin. In non sapien pellentesque lectus pretium faucibus. Integer eget sollicitudin velit.
          Curabitur eget nunc blandit, maximus lacus quis, congue ipsum. Nam varius hendrerit venenatis.<br/><br/> Morbi hendrerit velit mollis, efficitur nisi imperdiet, vehicula sapien. Aliquam diam orci, ornare ut luctus vitae, faucibus vel
          purus. Mauris auctor pellentesque lacus. Maecenas porttitor felis nec nulla vulputate, ut commodo nunc scelerisque. Sed luctus vitae elit tempor porttitor. Morbi consectetur ante iaculis erat bibendum, eget viverra nunc rutrum. Phasellus placerat,
          lorem consequat ultrices auctor, dui nunc imperdiet justo, a facilisis elit lacus nec mi. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.<br/><br/> Pellentesque aliquam, diam quis pulvinar mattis, sem neque tristique erat, a tincidunt
          elit nisi et est. Duis lorem ipsum, pulvinar eu eros eu, feugiat luctus diam. Cras eget molestie massa. Quisque quis mi quis urna interdum bibendum. Pellentesque at leo varius, placerat ipsum sed, convallis tortor. Integer ut volutpat lorem,
          in efficitur nisl. Sed augue est, vulputate vitae tortor sit amet, molestie ultrices diam. In eget elit urna. Aliquam tincidunt tempor sollicitudin. Phasellus ac elit a risus mattis iaculis id id erat. Sed a mauris in tellus porttitor ornare.
          Pellentesque eget porttitor dui. Duis posuere, dui eu mollis varius, quam diam elementum velit, nec dignissim magna justo ut tellus.<br/><br/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">Created By Alex, 2020<br/>Last Updated 01012020</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the below line, there's no slide element defined. Try changing it to `slides.length`:

```
if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
```

Comment: There are more typos. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62323158/4529168).